# Yii: CUploadFile save as not working properly

Tags: php, yii, upload

I am trying to `upload` `pdf` file using `Yii's` CUploadFile. In my Controller:

```
$model->recipe_file_url = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'recipe_file_url');
$file = $model->recipe_file_url;
$model->recipe_file_url->saveAs('images\uploads\\' . $file);
```

It is supposed to save the file in `uploads` directory under `images` directory, but it uploads it in the root directory with this name `images\uploads\$file`. How to solve this? any help?

Comment: Add your **View** file code too Mr @Saani.

Comment: File is getting uploaded. Right? Problem is : File name is `images\uploads\$file` ? And, where is your `images` directory ? Inside `Web` folder or what ? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yup, it is getting uploaded and images directory is under root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i got it myself. It was simple, I tried:

```
$model->recipe_file_url->saveAs('images/uploads/' . $file);
```

and it worked!